# How can I verify the scripts in /lib/systemd/system-shutdown are being run?

Tags: shutdown, systemd

I have a simple script that I want to run just before shutdown. I'm trying to verify this script are being run but I'm not seeing any messages from my script on my system's debug serial, kernel log, or journalctl.

```
#!/bin/sh
# $:~/ ls -lh /lib/systemd/system-shutdown
# total 4.0K
# -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 243 Nov 30 00:00 myscript.shutdown

/usr/bin/echo "MY SCRIPT SAYS I'm echoing"
/usr/bin/echo "MY SCRIPT SAYS I'm echoing to stderr" >&2
/usr/bin/logger "MY SCRIPT SAYS hello from the journalctl"
/usr/bin/echo "MY SCRIPT SAYS directly to kmsg" | /usr/bin/tee /dev/kmsg
```

I'm not seeing any of these messages with journalctl, dmesg, or on systemd's terminal output. I am on a custom OS with a lot of custom mounts for system journals, so if my script "should" work then I can chalk it up to some weird behavior on my hardware.

But if my code actually shouldn't work the way I have it, then what would be a good way to verify the scripts within /lib/systemd/system-shutdown are running?